# Multiple rows in td

Tags: html, html-table

Stores `<td>` contain table with mulitple rows.  A store can have mulitple 
stores (rows).

See Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ak3wtkak/1/

The width of Stores and Quantity (`<th>`) columns should be same for mulitple rows on the second table. How to fix this or what is alternative approach?

[image]

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:300px">Product</th>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Stores</th>
      <th class="middle">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
      Item 1
      </td>
      <td>12345</td>
      <td colspan="3">
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Store Name 1</td>
              <td class="middle">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Store Name 2</td>
              <td class="middle">4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Store Name 3</td>
              <td class="middle">4</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is no easy way.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ak3wtkak/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use rowspan. 
Make the first 2 rows with rowspan of 3.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:300px">Product</th>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th>Stores</th>
      <th class="middle">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Item 1</td>
      <td rowspan="3">12345</td>
      <td>Store Name 1</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Store Name 2</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Store Name 3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```